# Vuetify font size different in production vs dev

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I am trying to deploy a small Vuetify app to production and have run into a strange font size issue. My app looks fine in development, but when I deploy it and run it in production my font size is tiny.

I am not sure if this is a webpack issue. When I deploy I'm using the standard npm run build. My view CLI version is 4.2.2. I'm using Material Design spec Roboto Font, as is default for Vuetify:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/typography/

My app looks fine otherwise, with all other styling rendering perfectly. I am not loading any unusual font files, so I don't think this is a relative path issue. I've deployed this to a root folder, too, not a subfolder.

Most of my styling is done like so

```
<v-card-subtitle class="font-weight-bold body-1">
```

I am deploying to IIS 7.

My package.json is pretty basic

```html
{
  "name": "vue-ipr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "dhtmlx-gantt": "^6.3.7",
    "esri-loader": "^2.13.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-videojs7": "^0.1.5",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Here is my vue.config.js

```html
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that another style sheet I was pulling in via a CDN to power one sub-element from a third party was overriding the root HTML font size, but only when I built for production. Thus, all my Vuetify relative font sizing was affected. I fixed the issue by putting in a CSS override on App.vue for the HTML element.